# Why doesn't the compare method work?

Tags: c++, string

I am trying to make vertices only if they don't already exist so in main I do:

p_graph is a pointer to class Graph where I am trying to compare vert1 which is a string to all other strings already in the graph and if it is there, I want to go to the else statement above. In class Graph I have the following code:

but when I look at the code with the debugger iterator "it" doesn't seem to getName(), which is another string in class Vertex, so comparison with string v can be done.  How should I fix this problem?

Here's Vertex Constructor:

Comment: Based on the shown code, it can't be determined what's going wrong! Can you show the constructor of `Vertex` and the `getName()` member?

Comment: Provide more context please

Comment: I don t understand your sentence "doesn't seem to getName(), which is another string in class Vertex, so comparison with string v can be done."

Comment: Are you sure the name of each vertex has been set? There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with your code.

Comment: @dzada getName() gets the name of Vertex and compare() compares the two string i.e. two vertex names at least that's what I want compare to do but it is not working.

Comment: well are you sure it doesn't work? your compiler may have recognized the getter ( getName() ) and optimized away the function call. otherwise I don't see any problem with your code. simple test: print out the result of the comparison.

Comment: Pro tip: if you rename `i` to `vertex_number`, then you won't need the comment `i++; // increments vertex number`, because the code `vertex_number++;` would document itself.

Comment: @JonathanPotter Yes names of vertices are being set, I can see that in my debugger, but vertexInGraph() is not working due to skipping the compare method, just don't know what could be the cause?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, it looks as if you don't insert your vertex into a graph after creating it:

```
if (!(p_graph->vertexInGraph(vert1))) { // if vert1 is not already in graph
   v1 = new Vertex(vert1, i);
   i++; // increments vertex number
   }
```

This piece of code probably needs something like

```
p_graph->insertVertex(v1);
```

Comment: But my Graph has a vector<Vertex> vertices that I iterate through in the code above isn't that going to take care of storing vertices in the graph?

Comment: @Napalidon: even if your Graph has a `vector<Vertex>`, someone needs to actually add elements to it. Otherwise it will sit there empty no matter how many instances of `Vertex` you create. There's also some kind of problem, that if you have a `vector<Vertex>` then the elements intended for it shouldn't be created with `new`. That's not how `vector` works.

Comment: I'm looking over my code now and it seems that I forgot to write a function to put vertices in the vector<Vertex>.

Comment: Yes, just tested it and the problem was gone. Thanks, great catch!